# Subproces.call executing c++ script fails

Tags: python, c++, subprocess, os.system

In order to execute a c++ script I made, I am using:

```
subprocess.call(args, shell=True)
```

Whenever I execute this script via console, it prints 2 strings (one at the beginning and another at the end) and creates a file (output.txt)
My problem is that when I use the line above in python, although it prints the 2 strings it does not create the output.txt file that I so much need.

Any ideias of what this problem might be?

Thanks in advance!

Note:
I have already tried to execute the python script as sudo, it didn't work. I also tried without the shell=True and with os.system, same problem. I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Where are you looking for the file?

Comment: Ho God. Newbie mistake.
Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently the file was being created on the folder the python script was running (instead of the C++ script).

Thank you Immibis for your help.